# Does JavaScript support fixed-length array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know that JS has a data type Array:

```js
let arr = new Array()
```

But this array is a high level data structure. It can pop, push ....

I want to get a native array, just like C or Java. When it is created, it's length is immutable.

So How can I get it?

Comment: what do you mean by "native array"? Arrays in JS are objects, you can create one like that or using a literal `const arr = []`

Comment: Google "JavaScript typed array"

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would be an immutable array be used for? If that is what a native array means.

Comment: I believe you mean an array which has a fixed maximum length?

Comment: Do you want a "fixed-length" array? It always has `n` elements (even though some may be `undefined`) and cannot go over `n` (e.g. `arr.push(1)` throws an error or simply doesn't work)?